# Scrape result from website based on the search result using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to derive output based on search result from the [website](https://www.centris.ca/). Here is the step by step process:

1. Take the address "4065 avenue Wilson, Côte-des-Neiges / Notre-Dame-de-Grâce"
2. Navigate to https://www.centris.ca/
3. Put the address in the search bar
4. If there is a match suggestion, then return "Yes"
5. If there is no match, then return "No"

As you can see in Screenshot,(right) address `4065 avenue Wilson, Côte-des-Neiges / Notre-Dame-de-Grâce` shows `address suggestion` below the search box so script should return `Yes`

while (left) address `7919 -7921 avenue Henri-Julien, Villeray / St-Michel / Parc-Extension` shows `Aucun résultat trouvé` below the search box so script should return `No` :

[image: Merged]

I tried to develop a script but it shows **Invalid Argument** on `searchUrl` line.

```
function searchCentris() {
  const address = "4065 avenue Wilson, Côte-des-Neiges / Notre-Dame-de-Grâce";
  const searchUrl = `https://www.centris.ca/en/properties?searchType=geographic&searchMode=form&grid={%22viewport%22:{%22ne%22:{%22lat%22:45.55871812477478,%22lng%22:-73.53681564331054},%22sw%22:{%22lat%22:45.438517174044384,%22lng%22:-73.70114135742189}},%22location%22:{%22lat%22:45.49876419602977,%22lng%22:-73.61897850036623}}&locale=en`;  
    
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(searchUrl).getContentText();
  
  if (html.includes(address)) {
    return "Yes";
  } else if (html.includes("Aucun résultat trouvé")) {
    return "No";
  } else {
    return "Unknown";
  }
}
```

Can you please guide me how to resolve this issue and get the required output. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can't speak for the match suggestion, but that site generates data for that page dynamically from javascript. You can't scrape data from that page.

Comment: Could you review the URL you are using inside the URL Fetch. I tried to manually access to the URL `https://www.centris.ca/en/properties?searchType=geographic&searchMode=form&grid={%22viewport%22:{%22ne%22:{%22lat%22:45.55871812477478,%22lng%22:-73.53681564331054},%22sw%22:{%22lat%22:45.438517174044384,%22lng%22:-73.70114135742189}},%22location%22:{%22lat%22:45.49876419602977,%22lng%22:-73.61897850036623}}&locale=en` but I'm getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your code, the **url** assigned to `searchUrl` variable is not in correct format. How about trying the following script:

```
function searchAddress() {
  var url = 'https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetSearchAutoCompleteData';
  var payload = {
    text: "4065 avenue Wilson, Côte-des-Neiges / Notre-Dame-de-Grâce",
    searchType: 1,
    language: 'en',
    useSeoFriendlyUrl: false
  };
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  if(data.d.Result[0] == null){
       return "No";
  }
  else{
       return "Yes";
  }

  
}
```

I tested it and it returned the correct values for both urls that you provided in the question.

Comment: I ran the script and it worked perfectly. thank you for your answer..